# Ubuntu 20.04.2 Ralink MT7601U Wireless Drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, ralink

I just installed Ubuntu (after installing Kali which was a huge mess). This is my first time ever properly using Linux, and I would like to connect to the internet.
My Ubuntu release is 20.04.2, and I have the Ralink MT7601U Wireless Adapter, however the drivers for it seem to not be installed.
How can I install the drivers, or if they are already installed how can I connect to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Mediatek bought ralink few years ago.

MT7601U is included in kernel since 4.2

You don't need to install any drivers.

Just plug and go to network settings to select your Wifi network.